# delete[] a specific array block allocated with new in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, new-operator

I am writing a simple stack program in c++. I have dynamically allocated the array.
I was wondering if there's any way to delete(deallocate) the specific block of an array.

```
  int *arr = NULL ;
  arr = new int[some_size];
  .
  .
  .
  .
  //now suppose I want to deallocate a specific block
  //suppose 
  int i = 4;

  //can I do something like

  delete[i] arr;
```

I know this is sort of dumb question but still I would like to know.
Thank you.

Comment: `std::vector` is the container you are looking for.

Comment: @NathanOliver ok but how... can you please explain

Comment: See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for how to use it.

Comment: it should be delete[] arr. you don't need to mention index there. you can't deallocate specific element in that

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks but, is there any way possible with an array

Comment: @Sanjeev so you are saying that there's no way for that right....

Comment: yes, the memory allocation happened for block.

Comment: "_I am writing a simple stack program_" - No, you are not. if you implement your own allocatior to work this way, it'll be far from simple, but I don't think it's a dumb question.

Comment: You must delete the same thing you did in new.  They should always be 1:1.

Answer (score 5):

It is only possible to deallocate the entire allocation - not parts of it. There is no such syntax as `delete[i]`. Only a pointer returned directly from `new[]` may be passed to `delete[]`.

---

However, you can implement your own allocator that can work on a single block from the global allocator, giving smaller allocations that can be deallocated individually. This is an advanced technique: Not for beginners. It is (probably) not something that you need to do to implement any program. But in some cases it can be useful for optimisation if you know what you are doing.

> how am I going to implement my own allocator

Allocate some memory M from the global allocator.

Write a function that takes the number of bytes as argument. In the function, use some data structure to keep track of which parts of M have previously been allocated. Pick a range of bytes from M which has not been allocated. Mark it as allocated in the data structure, Return a pointer to the beginning of that range.

Write another function that takes a pointer as argument. Mark the memory that was reserved for that allocation as being free.

Even better, implement a type using these functions that conforms to the Allocator concept in the standard library so that the allocator can be used as a template argument to standard containers.

Comment: can you please explain it with an example please... like how am I going to implement my own allocator

Comment: @VaibhavBisht *can you please explain it with an example please..* -- Creating your own allocator is an advanced topic, not something that can be explained in a single SO answer block.  Also, your original post says "I am writing a simple stack program in c++", so why would you introduce anything beyond simple?

Comment: agree with @PaulMcKenzie, I am relating it to something to write your own memory manager.

Comment: @VaibhavBisht you likely don''t want to at this stage of your learning. `std::deque` does all the work you need, so start with that and work your way up.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays a kind of data structure that can store a fixed-size sequential collection of elements of the same type.

Arrays have a very special property of continuous memory allocation which means compiler allocates consecutive blocks of memory to a array.It gives array advantages such as

1. **random access** of elements
2. **binary search**
3. **less memory** consumption(as no pointer pointing to next element is required)

So , in general it is not possible to delete a specific block from a contiguous memory. So for this specific problem **Linked List** was invented.

But in C++ we have std:vector these are not static array but vectors which occupies more space than a static array.

Assuming that question is modified to vectors we can use pop_back function or erase function.

1.pop_back: Simply deletes the last vector .

```
    int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    print(numbers); 

    numbers.push_back(5);
    numbers.push_back(3);
    numbers.push_back(4);

    print(numbers); 

    numbers.pop_back();

    print(numbers); 
}
```

2.erase: Erases the specified elements from the container.

- Removes the    element at pos.
- Removes the elements in the range [first, last).

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/